# Dictionary query?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

I am using the following code to check for values of 1 or 0 stored in a dictionary file called 'myDict'. At position 'block003stored' is the value 1 and at all the other positions it's 0. If I use the following code I always get 0 returned for all positions:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
    if(myDict)
    {
    UIImageView *imageV = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    int myInt = [[myDict objectForKey:@"block%.3istored"] intValue];
        NSLog (@"value of i %d", i);
        NSLog (@"myInt %d", myInt);
    if (myInt == 1) imageV.hidden = FALSE;
    }
}
```

}

However if I change the objectForKey to specifically @"block003stored":

```
    int myInt = [[myDict objectForKey:@"block003stored"] intValue];
```

I get the correct value of 1 returned. I can't see why the code isn't working when I use the %.3i instead of 001, 002, 003 etc?

Comment: Try in a separate line: NSString *indexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:"block%.3dstored", i]; Then use the objectForKey:indexStr];

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just had to add @ in front of "block%.3dstored". :)

Comment: How do I tick this comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in a separate line:

```
NSString *indexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"block%.3dstored", i]; Then use the objectForKey:indexStr];
```

You were asking the dictionary to get the object with the key of "block%.3istored", which didn't exist. You need to apply formatting to get i in there.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the loop is using @"block%.3istored" as a literal string.  There's nothing in what you've written to format the string with the `i` variable.  Look at NSString's `stringWithFormat:` as a way of dynamically building the key.

Comment: Isn't there a length modifier you have to use instead of . for the language? According to this: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html it says to use an * to modify the field length.